# Is it safe to cast this to a base-class pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I'm currently learning C++, and this time I was messing with pointers, and studying the `this` pointer and polymorphism. My question is, is the conversion below safe, I know that basically I can access `m_uConnectedUsers` directly from `CUser` class because of 'public', but I may find an occasion where it will be needed, and I would like to know the opinion of you professionals about it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class CUserCounter
{
public:
    CUserCounter();
    virtual ~CUserCounter(){};

    BOOL m_bEmpty;
    u_long m_uConnectedUsers;
};

CUserCounter::CUserCounter()
{
    m_bEmpty = TRUE;
    m_uConnectedUsers = 0;
}

class CUser : public CUserCounter
{
public:
    CUser(LPCTSTR szName, BOOL bConnected, BOOL bChatting = FALSE );
    virtual ~CUser(){};

    BOOL m_bConnected;
    BOOL m_bIsChatting;
    TCHAR szCharName[32];

    bool IncreaseMoverMeter( unsigned uMeters );
};

CUser::CUser( LPCTSTR szName, BOOL bConnected, BOOL bChatting )
{
    if( szName )
    {
        if( strlen( szName ) > 30 )
            strcpy( szCharName, "Invalid" );
        else
            strcpy( szCharName, szName );
    }
    m_bConnected = bConnected;
    m_bIsChatting = bChatting;
}

bool CUser::IncreaseMoverMeter( unsigned uMeters )
{
    //is it safe? how does it works
    CUserCounter* pUserCounter = (CUserCounter*)this;
    if( pUserCounter )
    {
        pUserCounter->m_uConnectedUsers++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{             
    CUser *pUser = new CUser( "Jonh", FALSE );
    std::cout << pUser->IncreaseMoverMeter( 4 );

    system("pause>nul");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please don't care about 'unsigned uMeters' on IncreaseMoverMeter function, i've written this code quickly just for an example.

Comment: `CUserCounter* pUserCounter = (CUserCounter*)this` as the answer suggest though inheritance you already have access to all the public memebers using `this` `this->m_uConnectedUsers++;` is completely ok but try to use setters/getters even internally.

Comment: On top of all of the other comments and answers (all of which, at least so far, are correct), you should also avoid using C-style casts like (CUserCounter *)this; instead, write static_cast<CUserCounter *>(this). Besides making your intentions more explicit, it's also something you can grep for or use automated refactoring tools on.

Comment: Also, "public" isn't really relevant here. If the variable were private, you'd get the same error with the cast as without it, because a CUser method can't access private variables of a CUserCounter object—whether via the this pointer or via an explicit pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's safe, but also not necessary. :)

The conversion is implicit, so no need to cast.

`CUser` **is a** `CUserCounter` (at least in your design), so a pointer to a `CUser` is also a pointer to a `CUserCounter`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to discuss a larger issue than the one explicitly in the question.

You have CUser deriving from CUserCounter. This seems like a mistake, as a user *is not* a counter. In this case you should have an *has-a* relationship - the CUser object should contain a CUserCounter object, not be one.

To answer the question, a derived class can access any members of a base class that it wants. No casting required, and in fact casting can hide some nasty problems - avoid it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: This is all true, but it's not an answer to the question; maybe it would be better as a comment on the question?

Comment: @abarnert, I considered that but decided it's too important a point to be buried in the comments. It renders the whole question moot.

Comment: Granted—but the exact same issue could arise with a well-designed hierarchy. Just s/CUserCounter/User/g, and s/CUser/PowerUser/g and the question is not moot. That being said, it's worth suggesting that the questioner make that change, so his question is more directly meaningful.

Comment: @abarnert, you're correct of course so I added a bit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ususally it is not recommended to put member variables in the public.  Instead make them private and provide a public getter and/or setter method.

If you *have to* access the variable from derived classes, make it protected

The reason for this is that member variables represent the state of the object, and allowing direct modification is not recommended as it allows changes to the state in ways that breaks the underlying logic of the class (think of a String class: if you can directly modify the variable holding the cache of the size of the string that can wreak havok on further use of the object if the character array is not re-sized accordingly as well)

As for the `this` pointer: in most contexts you do not need to explicitly use it, its use can be decuced from the context.  However, if you have a member variable and a parameter in a member function with the same name, the parameter will hide the member variable, and you will have to use `this` to be able to access it.  (Similar effect comes to play when a derived class's member function hides the parent's function declarations)

You can access protected and public members of a class's parent class as well via `this`, but as noted above you usually do not need to use it.  Also, no conversion to (pointer to) the parent's type is needed in these cases

Comment: As with Mark Ransom's answer, this doesn't actually answer the question, even though it's true and useful information.

Comment: @abarnert - I believe I finally got to that part as well in my series of extensions to the answer :)

Comment: Yes, I think I wrote this right after your first edit, and before your second, third, and fourth… Now you are answering the question, and also providing lots of other useful info, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion such conversion is not only unnecessary but also inelegant. As someone said it's obvious that if you inherit from some class you have some fields/method available. You not only write some needless code, but also make your methods less readable and more difficult to maintain. The compiler would probably optimize such code and remove additional instructions so there might be no efficiency costs (but it's only my assumption). I strongly believe that when you think that `this` conversion is necessary there is a great probability that you should rethink your implementation once again.